# How to get the function name under a certain address in dll

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, dll

I've got this error message

```
[...]
# C  [FTDIIO.dll+0x1efb]
[...]
```

I have the dll, which is native, unmanaged code and the source code. I'd like to know the function, symbol (or even the codeline) und this particular address.

I'm not sure if it's important, but the dll is used by a JNI Java application with a custom (autogenerated) wrapper class for the dlls functions.

How to find the function, symbol or codeline at this particular address?

Comment: You need the map file or some equivalent debug output from the compilation that generated the DLL.

Comment: Thank you. So far, I found this tool http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html which gives me the addresses of the functions in the dll. But no address matches the address from the error message. I'm a little bit confused.